# loader not showing up in chrome-extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've an app that retrieve server data using ajax. I've tested in localhost, the loader work fine, but when I install my extension and click on the browser action popup, the loader won't show. The little popup delayed for 2 second and shows the result.

popup.html

```
<div class="cssLoader" ng-show="loader">Fetching...</div>
```

js

```
app.controller('MainControl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.loader = true;

    $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydomain.net/items.php",
        method: "GET",
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.loader = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the text `Fetching...` displaying ?

Comment: @Aperçu if I don't run in chrome extension browser action then yes.. the loader work but not in chrome extension.

Comment: I was just talking about if it's just the css that is not loaded or all the loader div, is there any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)**, CSP *"is necessary when developing things like Google Chrome Extensions"* (more info can be found on the linked page).

Furthermore, besides defining `ng-csp` on your root element, there is on more crucial point (which affects `ngShow`/`ngHide`):

> CSP forbids JavaScript to inline stylesheet rules. In non CSP mode Angular automatically includes some CSS rules (e.g. `ngCloak`). To make those directives work in CSP mode, include the `angular-csp.css` manually.

I found this to be necessary only if the `angular.js` script is defined inside the app's context.

---

In any case, here is the source code of minimal demo extension that seems to work fine for me:

**Structure:**

```
extension-root-dir/
    |_____manifest.json
    |_____popup.html
    |_____popup.js
    |_____angular.js
    |_____angular-csp.css
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        //"default_icon": {
        //     "19": "img/icon19.png",
        //     "38": "img/icon38.png"
        //},
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Extension</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-csp.css" />
    </head>
    <body ng-csp ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <div ng-show="loader">Fetching...</div>
        <div ng-hide="loader">{{status}}</div>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.loader = true;

    $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydomain.net/items.php",
        method: "GET"
    }).finally(function () {
        $scope.loader = false;
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.data   = response.data;
        $scope.status = 'Success !';
    }, function (response) {
        $scope.status = 'ERROR !';
    });
});
```

(BTW, I am using AngularJS `v1.2.16`.)

Comment: so what is the crucial part of my problem?         <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-csp.css" /> ??

Comment: I mean download it from somewhere (e.g. http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-csp.css), save it in your extension's directory and include it in your HTML (`<link ... />`). As I wrote in my answer, the extension above works perfectly on my latest Chrome. Pleases try to run it in your PC and see if it works for you as well. If that doesn't work, please post more code, so we can identify the issue.

Comment: as both @ExpertSystem and myself have pointed out, ng-csp is critical for using Angualr with Chrome Extensions. If ng-csp is not solving your problem then you're either not implementing it properly or you have other code issues. Without seeing your more of your code, it will be very difficult to isolate down which one it is.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more of your code it is difficult to know for sure. Nonetheless, my suspicion (based upon the fact that your code works outside of the Chrome extension environment but not inside that environment) is that since you're operating in a Chrome Extension environment, you'll need to include the ng-csp directive (see [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/angular_framework) or [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)).

I developed an Angular app inside a chrome extension and I needed to use ng-csp in order for Angular to load and fully function properly.

Essentially, Chrome extensions (and even more apps) place a number of restrictive security permissions on the browser environment and ng-csp tells Angular to operate in a way that is more consistent with a strict CSP.

I have included an example below that shows loading the entire Angular application properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-csp>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include in the next line your Angular library code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-lib.js"></script>
    <!-- Include in the next line your custom Angular code such as the $http to load the loader -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Place your HTML code for the 'Fetching' anywhere here in the body -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include an example of the directive?

Comment: I don't get it. pls post example.

Comment: I wrote      <html ng-app ng-csp>
but nothing happen.

Comment: I now included an example that shows how to fully load and bootstrap the Angular application in a fashion that everything else you do (such as making the $http call) should work properly.