# $http async in angularjs using GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.loader = true;

$http({
    url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/something.php",
    method: "GET",
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.loader = false;
});
```

How to make my request async?
My css loader didn't show up, so I suspect it's the async issue.

Comment: You only use the `.success` handler. Are you sure the there was no error ? Try adding `.error` handler as well

Comment: you might have not used the "loader" properly to show the loader

Comment: possible duplicate of [loader not showing up in chrome-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865518/loader-not-showing-up-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: @IgorMalyk no error..

Comment: Is the success callback fired ?

Answer (score 0):

You request is already async.

Can't you show your HTML and give an example of the data you're waiting for?